# ¿Cómo dar formato a un txt en golang?

Tags: go

Tengo un json el cual es dinámico y que convierto a txt:
EJEMPLO DEL JSON:

```
{name : luis, apellido: gomez, numero_id : 87846516}
```

mi codigo donde lo convierto es asi:

```
file, _ := json.MarshalIndent(string(jsonData), "", " ")

datos := ioutil.WriteFile("test.txt", file, 0644)
```

Lo convierto a txt exitosamente pero necesito darle un formato especifico en el que solo aparezcan los valores sin etiquetas y separados de la siguiente manera:

```
luis | gomez | 87846516
```

El formato no se como darselo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí la respuesta:

```
count := len(columns)
values := make([]interface{}, count)
valuePtrs := make([]interface{}, count)
for i := range values {
    valuePtrs[i] = &values[i]
}

for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(valuePtrs...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    concat := make([]string, 0)
    for i, _ := range columns {
        v := values[i]

        b, ok := v.([]byte)
        if ok {
            concat = append(concat, string(b))
        } else {
            concat = append(concat, fmt.Sprintf("%v", v))
        }
    }
    line := strings.Join(concat, " | ")

    log.Println("",line)
    _, err = f.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", line)))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Con esto ya no pasa por el json, solo va directo de la base de datos al archivo txt.